# Fetch API promise - JavaScript and HTML connection

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, post

I am very new to HTML and JavaScript. I have created a very simple HTML page for log-in functionality. The code is as below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <p>Username</p>
                <input type='text' name="" placeholder="Enter Username/Email ID">
                <p> Password</p>
                <input type='password' name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
                <input type='submit' name="" value="LogIn the User">
            </form>         
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Now I have a RESTful API having login functionality. I can send the values of Username and Password for API testing in POSTMAN in the json format.

[image]

Now my question is how can I connect the rest of API of login with my HTML page. If it is a duplicate question then please bring me to the original one. Also, if you can suggest some resources. I have gone through a lot but could not find the relevant.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps would be to

1. intercept the submit event on the form
2. parse the form to create the JSON you want to submit
3. submit the json
4. do something with the response

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function(e) { // when they submit
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't try and submit the form the traditional way
    const data = {
        username: e.target.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value,
        password: e.target.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value
    } // get the JSON we want to submit
    fetch('/auth/login', {
        method: 'post', // submit it as a post request
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json(); // parse the response as json
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log('do something with the response');
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <p>Username</p>
                <input type='text' name="username" placeholder="Enter Username/Email ID">
                <p> Password</p>
                <input type='password' name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                <input type='submit' value="LogIn the User">
            </form>         
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```